# Расширенная подсветка синтаксиса

Tags: vim

Можно ли заставить `vim` подсвечивать не только стандартный синтаксис (`c`: `for`, `#include<>`, `if`, ..), но и типы, включенные из (`c++`) хэдэров (`string`, `vector`, ..), а также те, что создаются в процессе написания кода:

```
class Alfa {
}
```

(чтобы `Alfa` подсвечивалась)

Как это сделать?

Comment: ИМХО, в стандартной поставке -- нет. Потому что для подсветки используются регулярные выражения. А они от кода не изменяются. ИМХО